# Scss not prependending variables or global scss on indivdual scss modules in sveltekit

Tags: typescript, sass, svelte, sveltekit

Hi I'm new to svelte and having an issue with using scss, im trying to prepend the data so that it prepends to every single example.module.scss file however when I try to run locally, I am always given error that it cannot find the right variables

SvelteKit Project File System

```
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── playwright.config.ts
├── src
│   ├── app.d.ts
│   ├── app.html
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Header
│   │   │   ├── Header.component.svelte
│   │   │   └── Header.module.scss
│   │   └── footer
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── +layout.svelte
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── +error.svelte
│   │   │   └── +page.svelte
│   │   └── layout.module.scss
│   └── scss
│       ├── main.scss
│       ├── mixins.scss
│       └── variables.scss
├── static
│   └── favicon.png
├── svelte.config.js
├── tests
│   └── test.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

---

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        vitePreprocess({
            scss: {
                prependData: '@use"./src/scss/main.scss" as *;'
            }
        }),
    
    ],

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

---

vite.config.ts

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}'],
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: `@use './src/scss/main.scss'as *;`,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

---

main.scss

```
@use "mixins";
@use "variables.scss";
```

variables.scss

```
$color-black: #0A0A0A;

    $color-white: #f5f5f5;

    $font-primary:'Poppins',

    sans-serif;
```

error

```
Internal server error: [sass] Undefined variable.
  ╷
4 │     background-color: $color-black;
  │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/components/Header/Header.module.scss 4:23  root stylesheet
```

```
Package Json 
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.2.4",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.15.9",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.26.0",
        "prettier": "^2.8.0",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.8.1",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "svelte": "^3.54.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```